# Ruby on Rails: Mac OS X 10.6 installation fail. Please help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, installation

I have just completed the tryruby.org tutorial, followed by the rubyforzombies.org tutorials and all was well.
Then I moved onto installing Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.4 using my Mac Os X 10.6 terminal, so far so good.

I have created a rails app via the command line as follows:

```
$ rails new ~/Sites/_ruby/rail3sqlite

$ cd rails3sqlite

$ rails server
```

The folder and file structure is being generated successfully but when I run the last line `rails server` I simply get an error saying:

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources 
listed in your Gemfile.
```

How can I get this working?

It seems to me the setup of this is harder than learning the language at this point.

Either way it would be awesome if someone could help me with this setup issue.

So far I have only been using MAMP to run PHP locally (which sets up everything automagically for me) so I am used to using MySQL as opposed to SQLite.

Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Are there GUI tools for SQlite such as PhpMyAdmin for MySQL?

How can I get rails working with MySQL? (I tried adding the `-d mysql` option into the rails new command but then I get the same error as above with `mysql2` as opposed to `sqlite3`.

Thanks,
Jannis

**Update:**

So I followed the advice below and ran `$ bundle install` within my `ruby3sqlite` directory and this was returned in the console:

---

```
Jannis:rail3sqlite Jannis$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
/Users/Jannis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:184:in `rescue in fetch_path': SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sqlite3-1.3.3.gemspec.rz) (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
```

Followed by all of these lines:

```
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:176:in `fetch_path'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:111:in `fetch_spec'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:47:in `_remote_specification'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:53:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:101:in `block in __dependencies'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:98:in `each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:98:in `__dependencies'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:68:in `activate_platform'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:325:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `block in resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:160:in `start'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:151:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:85:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:35:in `run'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in `install'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/Jannis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
Jannis:rail3sqlite Jannis$ rails server
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

If you have any ideas what those lines mean and what I need to do I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks for the suggestions so far! Much appreciated.

---

**Update 2:**

So it seems the above was just temporary, maybe the gems server was down or my ISP was having an issue? Who knows… either way I re ran the `bundle install` command and everything is now working as it should.

Thanks.

Comment: you might need to install sqlite3 from macport or compile from sqlite3 source. if you have macport already try, `sudo port upgrade sqlite3` and then run, `sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby`

Comment: Thanks, I installed Macports but running the second command I only get the return: `Error: Port sqlite3-ruby not found`. How do I know/find out which version I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 3, the gems that your project depends on are listed in `Gemfile` in the root of your project directory. You need to run `bundle install` to (1) ensure that your applications dependencies are installed, and (2) generate the `Gemfile.lock` that determines exactly which versions of these gems your application should use. (Note that the one command does both of those things for you.)

Once you've run `bundle install`, you should be able to start your development server using `rails server`.

[Edit]

You can learn more about Bundler, the system that manages your `Gemfile`, at [the Bundler homepage](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I went into the dir and ran `$ bundle install` but that returned a `fetch error` (I have updated the above with the full error (long list). I tried understanding the error message/trace but couldn't quite get it.

Comment: Update 2: Seems it might have just been a temporary fail. Just came back to it and re-ran the same `bundle install` command and now I'm up and running! Yay. One final thing… how can I get it to run on a custom domain (locally) instead of localhost:3000? I might need to run more than 1 ror app at a time so I must find a way to path to those such as app1.local:3000 app2.local:3000 etc.. can that be done?

Comment: @Jannis that would be like Apache virtual hosts I think

Comment: @mathepic, yea, I've got that part relatively figured out, but in order to make a host entry I would still need some unique address for these to sites to run on,… I will have to do some research I guess. Thanks though!

Comment: Check `rails server -h`; you can pass a custom port by passing `-p portnum` or `--port=portnum`, so for example `rails server -p 8080`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to `cd rails3sqlite3` and then `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a procedure for Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.2/RVM on Snow Leopard 10.6... and threw it up on a site. Have a look, it might help with some of your issues.

http://railsonosx.com

Answer (score 0):

For a fresh rails4 (ruby 2) setup on Mac, checkout this blog post:

http://blog.parsalabs.com/blog/2013/08/27/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-4-development-environment-on-a-clean-mac-os-x-installation/

I have tried and tested this method on my own mac. thought I'd share it with the community. hope you will find it useful.